# Extra space when scrolling using fixed height

Tags: html, css

I have a wrapper with elements inside that obviously I want to scroll when there are more elements than the box can hold. However when I scroll below the last word it has a large amount of excess space. I believe this may be caused by the fixed height. I have tried using max and min height but doesn't seem to fix it [Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEOtz.png)

Comment: We need code, preferably also included in a jsfiddle, to look at. Your image provides us almost no information whatsoever that would aid us in helping you, we need to see what you're doing and the image doesn't tell us that.

Comment: [Gif of the problem](https://gyazo.com/6eec0f1bb0aa55986c03aa3dfe3cf676). [Code](http://pastebin.com/PWaSX48p)

Comment: Sorry JS Fiddle wasn't showing an output for some reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSFiddle was choking on your code because you were double terminating your icons. I removed the double `</i>` and the code resolved fine on JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uwtcje0L/

With that said, the reason for your issue was pretty easily identified, you have 400px of padding on the bottom of `div.communitieswrapper`. Replace the CSS class you provided with the following:

```
.communitieswrapper{
  border: 2px solid #eeeeee;
  border-radius: 7px;
  padding-top:10px;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
  height: 450px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Fiddle with example: https://jsfiddle.net/uwtcje0L/1/

Comment: Wow, yea I was using that to see what it looked like without text when i started and forgot to remove it. I have another question however if you don't mind. The section that contains "Communities and Teams" I would like that to be fixed into the div so only the content scroll, almost like a header. I have tried a few methods that don't seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: @System https://jsfiddle.net/uwtcje0L/3/

Bear in mind that the majority of your styling is missing from the fiddle so you will likely have to tweak pixel values, but this gets you started.

Comment: @System I am happy to continue assisting you with other questions but if you wouldn't mind marking my answer as the solution it will help prevent people from coming in thinking that the issue still needs solved. (Fills in marker as solid green showing that the question has been answered)

Comment: @System glad I was able to assist. :)